# Analytic function on a circumference

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic inside and over the circumference given by $|z|= R$. Let $z=re^{i\theta}$ point inside the circle, proof that: $$f(re^{i\theta}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{R^2-r^2}{R^{2}-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)+r^{2}}f(Re^{i\theta})d\phi $$

By the Cauchy's integral formula we have: $$f(re^{i\theta})= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{f(z)}{z-re^{i\theta}}dz $$

But $z=re^{i\theta}$, then I have a division by 0, so I don't really understand how to start, if anyone can help me I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write down everything in polar coordinates, but remember that you are integrating on $|z|=R$, so it would be better to write $\zeta=Re^{i\phi}$ for the integration variable, because $r$ and $\theta$ are already in use for the fixed point $z=re^{i\theta}$.
Cauchy formula is
$$f(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f(Re^{i\phi})}{Re^{i\phi}-re^{i\theta}}d(Re^{i\phi})$$
Now, $d(Re^{i\phi})=iRe^{i\phi}d\phi$, because $R$ is fixed, so
$$\frac{d(Re^{i\phi})}{Re^{i\phi}-re^{i\theta}}=iRe^{i\phi}\frac{d\phi}{e^{i\phi}(R-re^{i(\theta-\phi)})}=iR\frac{d\phi}{R-re^{i(\theta-\phi)}}=iR(R-re^{i(\phi-\theta)})\frac{d\phi}{R^2+r^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)}$$
On the other hand
$$\frac{r^2-Rre^{i(\phi-\theta)}}{R^2+r^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)}=\frac{re^{-i\theta}(re^{i\theta}-Re^{i\phi})}{(Re^{i\phi}-re^{i\theta})(Re^{-i\phi}-re^{-i\theta})}=\frac{re^{-i\theta}}{re^{-i\theta}-Re^{-i\phi}}=\frac{Rre^{i(\theta-\phi)}}{Rre^{i(\theta-\phi)}-R^2}=\frac{\zeta\bar{z}}{\zeta\bar{z}-R^2}$$
is a holomorphic function of $\zeta$, therefore
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{r^2-Rre^{i(\phi-\theta)}}{R^2+r^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)}f(Re^{i\phi})d\phi=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|\zeta|=R^2}\frac{\zeta\bar{z}}{\zeta\bar{z}-R^2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta}d\zeta$$
and, by the Cauchy formula, the last integral is just the value of the function
$$\frac{\zeta\bar{z}}{\zeta\bar{z}-R^2}f(\zeta)$$
for $\zeta=0$, i.e. $0$.

Therefore
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{-Rre^{i(\phi-\theta)}}{R^2+r^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)}f(Re^{i\phi})d\phi=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{-r^2}{R^2+r^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)}f(Re^{i\phi})d\phi$$

Now, we just put everything together:
$$f(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f(Re^{i\phi})}{Re^{i\phi}-re^{i\theta}}d(Re^{i\phi})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{R(R-re^{i(\phi-\theta)})f(Re^{i\phi})}{R^2+r^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)}d\phi={\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{(R^2-r^2)f(Re^{i\phi})}{R^2+r^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)}d\phi}$$

which is the representation formula given by the Poisson kernel for harmonic functions.

*Note*: there are shorter derivations of this result, which start by searching for a real reproducing kernel, so you basically take
$$\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta- z}$$
and try to correct
$$\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta- z}+\frac{d\bar{\zeta}}{\bar{\zeta}-\bar{z}}$$
in order to obtain another reproducing kernel,
by showing that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)d\bar{\zeta}}{\bar{\zeta}-\bar{z}}=f(0)$$